# How do you install kvm on CentOS 5.3 using yum?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to get kvm installed on CentOS 5.3. Doing "`yum install kvm`" doesn't quite work. The problem is that the Intel kvm kernel modules won't load:

```
# modprobe kvm-intel
FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found.
```

The kvm kernel modules (in the kmod-kvm package) are compiled against kernel `2.6.18-160.el5`, but I'm running 2.6.18-164.el5. This means that the kernel module I need to load is `/lib/modules/2.6.18-160.el5/extra/kmod-kvm/`, but since I'm not running this version of the kernel, it doesn't find the module if I try to load it.

The default kernel in CentOS 5.3 is `2.6.18-128.el5`. If I do a "`yum upgrade kernel`", I get 2.6.18-164.el5. As far as I can tell, the CentOS repositories don't have 2.6.18-160.el5. At least, I can't just do "`yum install kernel-2.6.18-160.el5`".

I thought I might pull down the kmod-kvm package as a source RPM and build it against my kernel, but doing `yumdownloader --source kmod-kvm` fails to locate a source version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

upgrade to 5.4 - it should have KVM inside.

before you do that, check your CPU flags (`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep vm`)

if you see the flag, but still can't enabe kvm, check the server BIOS - you might have VT disabled. if it was disabled, enable it and do a full powercycle of the server.

after that

```
modprobe kvm_intel
```

Comment: Yup, the upgrade did it.

Answer (score 0):

Once upgraded you can [follow this steps](http://eduardo-lago.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on.html) I wrote to install KVM on CentOS, It's mainly for CentOS 6.2 but I with a few adjustments you can do the same thing on CentOS 5.x.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.